# How to use "We require to know" or " We need to know" in an official correspondence?

Tags: word-usage, correspondence

How to use "We require to know" or " We need to know" in an official correspondence? How it is used when correspondence being done a. Within the organization and b. Outside the organization.

Comment: We require cannot be followed by to. We require knowing or We require  you to know.

Comment: @Lambie But grammatically one could say "We are required to know...". And that doesn't sound quite as imperious as "We require to know...", which in any event, as you rightly say, is not grammatical.

Comment: @WS2 We are required to know is fine but a different meaning than: we need to know, as the OP said.

Comment: @Lambie I suppose you could say "You are required to tell us..." , but it's a bit blunt, isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

From [Fowler's Modern English Usage, Second Edition](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XvSAl4Ng8SYC&pg=PT554&lpg=PT554&dq=%22require+to+know%22+to-infinitive&source=bl&ots=YeFKuoJ3Kx&sig=R35M-Nl7Pho6pn3PhXAaJkgf5s0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikj9vs8P3YAhWMDsAKHX1xDnAQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=%22require%20to%20know%22%20to-infinitive&f=false):

> The construction with a to-infinitive, as in
>
> *I require to know your names*,
>
> is not idiomatic in BrE, but is known in other varieties of English.

I'd say that the passives 'You are (not) required to ...', 'Are we required to ...' etc are totally idiomatic, if rather formal.

................

'We need to know ...' is totally grammatical, but lacking previous context is abrupt.

'As new regulations mean that we have to update our records, we need to know ...'.

'To help us expedite your order, we need to know ...'.

Answer (score 0):

In an official document, I would use the passive voice: "The following information is required".

Comment: As @MετάEd has said, 'Answers which consist of virtually nothing but an unsupported statement or a citation are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers. For help writing a good answer, see _How to Answer._